# Odd behavior from canvas drawing other players using socket server

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas, socket.io

I'm trying how to learn how to create a multiplayer game using socket.io. I currently have a server storing all player's locations and sending every player their location, then sending the player everyone else's locations. I am getting those numbers as far as I know they are perfect. I have cross checked each of the locations and they are all like they are supposed to be. For some reason though, I have noticed when drawing the players to the canvas I get some weird behaviors. Here are some examples of what happens. Top left is the player's coordinates and the numbers under that are the other player's coordinates:
[image]
From this picture you can see that I can only see one of the players. And the player is towards the bottom left. This would be fine by itself. The other player could be far off in the would and not on the screen.

[image]
In this picture you can see the same thing as the first picture but there is another cube. Now this makes NO sense. The cube should be the lower left cube and the view should be shifted down to adjust for the cube's y being lower.

[image]
Now this picture is where things make no sense to me. You can only see the last cube and the blue cube is still displaying above and towards the left of the last cube when this cube should BE the last cube.

Here is the code I am using. This might not make any sense to you as this is my first try and needs major improvement. Here is the code for the server:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
var speed = 10

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/index.html");
});
app.use('client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
serv.listen(2000);

characterList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ".", ",", ":", ";", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "[", "]", "(", ")", "<", ">", "|"]
var players = []
var connections = []
var io = require('socket.io')(serv, {});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var address = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
  players.push({
    position: {
      x: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000),
      y: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)
    }
  })
  connections.push(socket.id)
  socket.on('request', function(data) {
    length = data.length
    if (data.request == 'sessionID') {
      socket.emit('sendSessionID', {
        id: socket.id
      });
    }
    if (data.request == 'players') {
      var otherPlayers = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (connections[i] != data.id) {
          otherPlayers.push(players[i])
        } else {
          socket.emit('packet', {
            packetType: 'self',
            player: players[i]
          });
          console.log[i]
        }
      }
      socket.emit('sendPlayers', {
        Players: otherPlayers
      });
    }

  });

  socket.on('moveEvent', function(data) {
    var player = players[find(connections, data.id)]
    if (data.direction == "x+") {
      player.position.x = player.position.x + speed
    }
    if (data.direction == "y+") {
      player.position.y = player.position.y + speed
    }
    if (data.direction == "x-") {
      player.position.x = player.position.x - speed
    }
    if (data.direction == "y-") {
      player.position.y = player.position.y - speed
    }
  });

  function find(arrayName, string) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
      if (string == arrayName[i]) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  function findKey(key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
      if (string == arrayName[i].ip) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    var address = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    players.splice(find(connections, this.id), 1)
    connections.splice(find(connections, this.id), 1)
  });
});
```

Here is the code for the Client using a single canvas element on the screen:

```js
$(function() {
  var socket = io();
  var sesID = ""
  var players = []
  var player = {}
  var game = document.getElementById('game')
  var gamectx = game.getContext('2d');
  var GameY = 0;
  var GameX = 0;
  var w = false;
  var a = false;
  var s = false;
  var d = false;
  socket.emit('request', {
    request: "sessionID"
  });

  socket.on('sendSessionID', function(data) {
    sesID = data.id
  });

  socket.on('sendPlayers', function(data) {
    players = data.Players
  });
  socket.on('packet', function(data) {
    if (data.packetType == 'self') {
      GameX = data.player.position.x;
      GameY = data.player.position.y;
      player = data.player;
    }
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(players.length)
    if (w == true) {
      socket.emit('moveEvent', {
        direction: "y+",
        id: sesID
      })
    }
    if (a == true) {
      socket.emit('moveEvent', {
        direction: "x+",
        id: sesID
      })
    }
    if (s == true) {
      socket.emit('moveEvent', {
        direction: "y-",
        id: sesID
      })
    }
    if (d == true) {
      socket.emit('moveEvent', {
        direction: "x-",
        id: sesID
      })
    }
    gamectx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    gamectx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    gamectx.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
    socket.emit('request', {
      request: "players",
      id: sesID
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      gamectx.fillStyle = "#ff0000"
      gamectx.fillRect(players[i].position.x + GameX, players[i].position.y + GameY, 100, 100)
      console.log('drew player at ', players[i].position.x + GameX, players[i].position.y + GameY, 100, 100)
    }
    gamectx.fillStyle = "#0000ff"
    gamectx.fillRect(window.innerWidth / 2 - 50, window.innerHeight / 2 - 50, 100, 100);
    gamectx.font = "48px sans-serif";
    gamectx.strokeText("x: " + GameX + ", y: " + GameY, 10, 50);
    var playersList = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      playersList += "x: " + players[i].position.x + ", y: " + players[i].position.y + ", "
    }
    gamectx.font = "30px sans-serif";
    gamectx.strokeText(playersList, 10, 100);
  }, 30);

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 65) {
      a = true;
    }
    if (e.which == 68) {
      d = true;
    }
    if (e.which == 87) {
      w = true;
    }
    if (e.which == 83) {
      s = true
    }
  });
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which)
    if (e.which == 65) {
      a = false;
    }
    if (e.which == 68) {
      d = false;
    }
    if (e.which == 87) {
      w = false;
    }
    if (e.which == 83) {
      s = false
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the html code if needed:

```html
<html>
<div id="location-div">
</div>
<canvas id="game"></canvas>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/game.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your help in advance if this makes any sense to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

### All is relative.

In 1D x & canvas center cc = 100.

You draw players `gameX + x` you draw self at `cc==100` So if self is 150 and player is 200 you draw player at `150+200=350` but self is drawn at cc making the player `350-cc = 250` pixels right of self. The player should be 50 pixel right of self `canvas.width/2 + 50`.

To fix draw players at the center of canvas (cc or origin) plus difference between self and player.

```
ctx.drawRect((canvas.width / 2) + (player.x - self.x), ...
```

**BTW**

To make a character array

```
charArr = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,:;!@#$%^&*()-_[]()<>|".split("");
```

Saves you much typing next time you need such an array.

Never rely on data continuity

Sending movement only and relying on each client to maintain correct position is never going to work, miss one packet on one machine and every one will have the wrong view. Send absolute position at time (time stamped) plus current delta. Not as a string but encode into smallest packet you can send.

Use player's last delta to update position if next packet is late. Revert to actual position when packet does arrive. Allow interaction rollback if you get missing packets late. Ie don't kill player if position was guessed from previous delta and new position proves the hit was a miss.

What does now mean?

Remember the speed of light is limited, you update at 30ms (3/100th second) this gives light (@~300,000,000mps) time to move 9,000,000m or 9000km, just enough time to move across a country and back, add packet switching, client processing, response transmission delay, etc, for world wide games expect min ping time 150ms + (or limit game to low ping (local) only) We all have different nows, code multiplayer with that in mind.